# Clojure how to change the return type of an operator?

Tags: clojure

first I am not looking for answer to this question I simplying looking for clarification. This is for a 4clojure question and the wording is a bit ambigious and doesn't seem to cover ever example. The question is: http://www.4clojure.com/problem/166

Text:

For any orderable data type it's possible to derive all of the basic comparison operations (<, ≤, =, ≠, ≥, and >) from a single operation (any operator but = or ≠ will work). Write a function that takes three arguments, a less than operator for the data and two items to compare. The function should return a keyword describing the relationship between the two items. The keywords for the relationship between x and y are as follows:
    x = y → :eq
    x > y → :gt
    x < y → :lt

1. I believe that compare can be used to implement all comparision operators. Am I correct?

   2. I believe the question wants me to change the return type of the less than operator and the greater than operator so that they return :lt, :gt, and :eq
   3. 4clojure does not allow defmacro.
   4. My question is am I correct in my assumption that I am supposed to overwrite the return type of < and >?
   5. If I am correct is there a way to do this with out a macro?
      Please do not post an answer for the 4clojure question, just a general clarification of the problem would help. The text also mentions writing a function that takes in < yet one of the examples uses >. So a bit confused on what is being asked for here. I am supposed to use the output of the function being passed into my function correct or am I suppose to write a function that overides the < and > operators inside the functions being passed in?

Answer (score 5, accepted):

The question is asking you to define a function like

```
(defn compare [lt x y] ...)
```

where `lt` is a function of two parameters which returns whether the first parameter is less than the first e.g.

```
(defn compare [lt x y]
   (if (lt x y)
     ...))
```

Comment: I actually already wrote one like that, but the issue is how to tell :eq if all the funcs return is true and false. 1. Returns false (< 5 1) yet expects :gt, two returns false yet returns :eq 3. Returns true and expects :lt which is consistent: (< 1 3) is true then 4. Returns false on (> 0 2) yet expects :gt hence it appears false should be :gt however the leaves how to interpret true. Thanks for the input.

Comment: @user561236 - You need to call `lt` twice which will give you two bool values, of which there are 4 possible combinations. One of these combinations (`true`, `true`) is invalid and indicates the `lt` function does not behave correctly. The other three possibilities correspond to the three possible outputs from your funciton.

Comment: Thanks might have been a little to mich info there, but I suppose thinking outside the box is an issue I need to work on :) thanked you in my answer's notes.

Answer (score 2):

In fact, there is a special function for that in clojure core: `comparator`. It generates the comparator from any function taking two args and returning truthy or falsey val. That comparator is itself a function, returning `-1` when function is true for arg1 and arg2, `1` when function is true for arg2 and arg1 and `0` otherwise:

```
user> ((comparator <) 1 2)
-1
user> ((comparator <) 2 1)
1
user> ((comparator <) 1 1)
0
user> ((comparator (fn [a b] (< (count a) (count b)))) [1 2 3] [4])
1
user> ((comparator (fn [a b] (< (count a) (count b)))) [] [4])
-1
user> ((comparator (fn [a b] (< (count a) (count b)))) [10] [4])
0
```

so, applied to the task from 4clojure it is enough to create the comparator, compare vals and get needed indicator for -1, 0 or 1.